# Get guild details from the user DM using Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created a discord bot which can be invited to guilds and has slash commands. Everything is working fine if a user uses the command in server. But I want to get the guild if user uses that command in bot DM.
How can I do that?

I have tried using message.guild but that is always returning None.

Comment: How would you get the server/guild from a DM? They don't have any connection, even Discord can't find that out. If you want to keep track of users that have used your bot inside of a server earlier and then DM'd your bot, then you should try using a database. From my experience, Firebase/Supabase work smoothly for Discord bots.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly retrieve a user's guild if the order was made in DM.
You can perhaps look at the member list on each server to see if he's in it, but this poses a problem because you could have duplicates if the guy is on two servers with your bot. You can also block mp commands from your bot (only some if necessary).

I'm not a python developer but I think this might help:

[Disscord.py guide lock mp](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=dm#discord.app_commands.AppCommand.dm_permission)